# Fixed fortify scan Locale changes are reappearing

Tags: java, fortify

I have one J2EE application and for that application, fortify scan shows Locale dependent issues.

I have fixed those issues where using Locale.ENGLISH in toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH) and toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH) functions while comparing the Strings,
Earlier,

```
firstName.trim().toLowerCase();
```

Now

```
firstName.trim().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

and I again run fortify scan on the application. However, second time, fortify scan shows Locale error at same place.

How can I fix these kind of issues?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue category "Portability Flaw: Locale Dependent Comparison" (RULEGUID=D8E9ED3B-22EC-4CBA-98C8-7C67F73CCF4C) belongs to the "Code Quality" kingdom and is a LOW RISK issue. I usually leave it un-remediated.

***RATIONALE*** 
When "java.lang.String.toUpperCase()/toLowerCase()" used without setting a locale, it will use the default locale. This may cause security checking being bypassed. For example, we want to exclude "script" from user input; if the default language is Turkish, the tag.toUpperCase() returns "T\u0130TLE", where "\u0130" is the "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE" character. Therefor the "script" checking is bypassed.

```
if (tag.toUpperCase().equals("SCRIPT")){
  return null;}
```

***REMEDIATION***

(1) you can set language when start VM, and mark the issue "Not an Issue"

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Duser.variant=US MainClass
```

(2) or, set language by code

```
import java.util.Locale;
//be aware that Locale.setDefault is global, below set locale to en_US_WIN
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US", "WIN"));
```

(3) or, if clients use different languages, use HttpServletRequest.getLocale

// see sample code [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=OpenClinica-master/ws/src/main/java/org/akaza/openclinica/controller/helper/SetUpUserInterceptor.java)